# How to implement authentication using remote actors?

Tags: actor, akka, remote-actors

I'm working on a card game and it seems like actors - specifically remote actors - would be a good fit. I'm having trouble figuring out how to implement the notion of logging in using remote actors. If a player starts up a fat client and enters a username and password, what should happen next? Should the client:

- have a User remote actor where some state changes to represent a successful login?
- call a method on an Authentication remote actor and get back a handle to a logged in User remote actor?
- something else entirely?

I'm also wondering how this would fit in with reconnecting after a network issue.

Answer (score 1):

Send an authentication message to a known remote actor, he responds with an actor you can talk to if successful, and a failure message if login failed. Profit

Comment: though this does not really stop leakage of actor names. Once the name is out any message could be sent by anyone to it.

Comment: [This later response in another thread is more detailed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921754/how-to-hide-akka-remote-actors-from-lookup/11922622#11922622) and gives a fuller answer to this question.